Data shows in Apple Health app Charts but not showing under Sources and All Data (HealthKit Integration)
I have integrated HealthKit in my Flutter app. I am writing the blood pressure readings from my app to Apple Health. Everything works fine without any errors.
The data is showing up in the charts (as circled) but the app is not showing up under the Sources or the All Data screens.
Anyone faced something similar before? What could be the issue?


I have the same problem on the simulator. The recorded data is displayed correctly on the device. Try to test this part on the device.

I have tried this on my physical devices too. The app is not showing up under the sources list. The values are only shown on the graph but not as a list of data.
